# Webdriver : How to upload a file using relative path in java?

Tags: java

Need to upload an image using the relative path, which I would like to run on both IDE and command line.

Here is the code which runs with the absolute path,

```
         File classpathRoot = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
         File picturesDir = new File(classpathRoot, "/pictures");
         File picture = new File(picturesDir, "profileImage.jpg");
         String picturePath = picture.getAbsolutePath();
```

Comment: So what is your specific issue?  Is your code returning an error?

Comment: How about `File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/pictures/profileImage.jpg");String picturePath = file.getAbsolutePath();` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.` to represent a relative path in your directory

So, if you used something like

```
classpathRoot, "../pictures"
```

For more details check here.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/pathOps.html